# Accessing Azure proxy enterprise app external URL from other registered app using ClientSecret in the background

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, console-application

I have following situation

**APP1 :** Azure enterprise application running through azure proxy. My external URL is https://xxx.msappproxy.net and internal URL for testing purpose I have put is https://reqres.in

Enterprise App is configured to allow login by any user, now this is all applicable when it runs from UI with specific user login, but as I am running the app from the background, I need to create APP2.

**APP2 :** I need to create another App which has a permission to access (with admin consent in place) enterprise proxy app (APP1). for that I have configured Client secret in APP2, I can successfully get the token from my App

I believe standard method is to set up client secret in APP2, allow permission to access APP1, get the token passing client secret and access APP2.

Following is my code to retrieve token for APP2 and access APP1 external URL.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("7cbb265a-cf6d-xxxx-xx-289bd24d0be0")
                                                      .WithClientSecret("1eanye2~.-I_K-69i4B8kahdkjasxxxlnr~3v")
                                                      .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/877b6ed6-377f-42d5-ab2e-xxxxxxx")
                                                      .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://7cbb265a-cf6d-4adf-8ae2-xxxxx/.default" };
            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            if(result != null)
            {
                string Need = result.AccessToken;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {result.AccessToken}");
                //HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://xxx.msappproxy.net/api/users");
                string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

All works fine and I get the token for APP2, but when I try to access proxy URL with Authorization, HTTPresponseMessage still ask me to login as in response rather then actual data from https://reqres.in/api/users,  I am getting whole Azure AD Authentication html page back asking me to authenticate.

I am not sure if I required anything additional configuration to be in done in either APP1 or APP2.

If you can help or give me some direction ahead making this possible would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Hiren.

Answer (score 0):

We can give delegate control to other application (app2) and users will be able to access it through app1. please see the below document for more details.

Delegate permissions.

Kindly check these [documents 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-delegate-app-roles#:%7E:text=In%20Azure%20AD%2C%20you%20can,aspects%20of%20applications%20they%20create.) and [document 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-concept-delegation)